# Get MongoDB Documents WHERE Status and Between Dates

Tags: mongodb, go, filter

I need to get all Documents from orders **Where**:

```
status == 'paid' AND status == 'delivered' AND
closed_at BETWEEN startDate AND endDate ;
```

I have reach to my mongoDB conecction with this code:

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo/options"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo/readpref"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    mx, err := time.LoadLocation("America/Mexico_City")
    endDate := time.Now().In(mx)
    startDate := endDate.AddDate(0, 0, -1)

    if err != nil { fmt.Println(err); return }

    client, err := mongo.NewClient(options.Client().ApplyURI("mongodb+srv://<userName>:<pass>@someDomain/orders"))
    if err != nil { fmt.Println(err); return }

    ctx, _ := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 10*time.Second)
    err = client.Connect(ctx)
    if err != nil { fmt.Println(err); return }
    defer client.Disconnect(ctx)

    err = client.Ping(ctx, readpref.Primary())
    if err != nil { fmt.Println(err); return }

    orders := client.Database("orders").Collection("orders") //here I want to filter with the status 'paid' and 'delivered' and closerd_at between dates.
}

func Bod(t time.Time) time.Time {
    year, month, day := t.Date()
    return time.Date(year, month, day, 0, 0, 0, 0, t.Location())
}
```

One more thing I have doubt, on the document, the `closed_at` has a format date like:

```
2020-04-23T21:28:46.642+00:00
```

And my `from` and `to` dates have a format like:

```
startDate: 2020-08-06 00:00:00 -0500 CDT
endDate:   2020-08-07 00:00:00 -0500 CDT
```

Comment: `status` cannot be both `paid` and `delivered`. If the dates are stored as date values (not strings) in the database, the formatting is not important, date comparison will compare the correct dates. You have to call the `Find` API on the collection with your query, and iterate over the results using the returned cursor.

Comment: So if i want all Document from status **paid** and **delivered** I need to do two calls from the data?

Comment: That is status=paid *or* status=delivered. Or, `status:{$in:["paid","delivered"]}`

Comment: It is in the *same attribute*, status can be paid or delivered so I think it's like: **status:{$in:["paid","delivered"]}**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was my solution:

```
query := bson.M{
    "status": bson.M{"$in":[]string{"paid","delivered"}}, //only status paid and delivered
    "closed_at": bson.M{"$gt": from, "$lt": to}, //between dates
}

cursor, err := client.Database("orders").Collection("orders").Find(ctx,query)
```

Reference to the answers: [MongoDB Compass Filter expression to Go bson.M expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63347906/mongodb-compass-filter-expression-to-go-bson-m-expression/63347934?noredirect=1#comment112016530_63347934)