# MongoDB Compass Filter expression to Go bson.M expression

Tags: mongodb, go, bson

I have a filter on **MongoDB Compass filter** Between two dates and an string of two posible values like this code:

```
{closed_at: {$gt: ISODate('2020-07-01T00:00:00.700+00:00'),$lt: ISODate('2020-07-30T00:00:00.700+00:00')}, status: { $in: ["paid", "delivered"] }}
```

[image]
**(I expect the same 1256 Documents if filter the same values on Go)**

Now I need to convert this filter to a valid bson.M expression, can´t find the trick for the "status" string filed, have this query expression but have an error message:

```
query := bson.M{
    "status" : ["paid", "delivered"], //Error: Invalid array bound '"paid"', the value must be representable by 'int' type
    "closed_at": bson.M{"$gt": from, "$lt": to},
}

cursor, err := client.Database("orders").Collection("orders").Find(ctx,query)
```

¿Which is the correct way to declare the **status field** and pass value **query** to Find method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't translate the query completely:

```
"status": bson.M{"$in":[]string{"paid","delivered"}}
```

Comment: Still get the message: Invalid array bound '"paid"', the value must be representable by 'int' type

Comment: @ElíGiacomelli, fixed the syntax

Comment: Fixed, but the consult return 0 documents, any idea why this happens?

Comment: Likely related to `from` and `to` dates. What are those?

Comment: You're right, I was filtering bad the dates **from** and **to** with a correct format works perfect, thanks @Burak Serdar